# Is every topos a De Morgan topos?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I think I'm getting something wrong, but I don't see what that is. Does anyboy see where is the error in the following argument.

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a nondegenerate topos. The topos $\mathcal{E}_{\neg\neg}$ of $\neg\neg$-sheaves is a boolean topos, so $\Omega_{\neg\neg}\cong 2$ in $\mathcal{E}_{\neg\neg}$, so let $h:\Omega_{\neg\neg}\rightarrow 2$ be such an isomorphism.

On the other hand, we have an inclusion functor $J:\mathcal{E}_{\neg\neg}\rightarrow\mathcal{E}$, so $h$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal{E}$ because $Jh=h$ is an isomorphism. Now, $2$ classifies complemented subobjects in $\mathcal{E}$ and $\Omega_{\neg\neg}$ classifies $\neg\neg$-closed subobjects in $\mathcal{E}$. But if $2\cong\Omega_{\neg\neg}$ in $\mathcal{E}$, then every $\neg\neg$-closed subobject is complemented ($\neg\neg\neg A=\neg A$ is true for every subobject $A$). Therefore, by Proposition 4.6.2(ii) in p. 999 in *Sketches of an Elephant*, $\mathcal{E}$ is De Morgan.

However, according to the comments in this question [Constructing a topos from a Heyting algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258831/constructing-a-topos-from-a-heyting-algebra), we can get a topos not being De Morgan. So there gotta be something wrong in the argument above, but I just don't see it. Where is the error in the previous argument?

Comment: Haven't processed the whole thing yet -- but it seems very possible that $2_{\mathcal{E}_{\lnot\lnot}}$ and $2_{\mathcal{E}}$ are different objects.

Comment: I think the above comment is right. For instance, if $\cal E$ is the effective topos, then $\mathcal{E}_{¬¬}$ is the topos of classical sets. The inclusion of the classical $2$ is usually written $\nabla 2$, and is not the same as the $2$ that is $1 + 1$ in the effective topos. $2 \subset \nabla 2$. $2$ is the (computably) decidable truth values, and $\nabla 2$ is the classical truth values (which carry no computational information).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 2 objects of $\mathcal{E}$ and of $\mathcal{E}_{\lnot\lnot}$ are not necessarily the same object.  (In fact, I think what your argument shows is that they are the same object if and only if $\mathcal{E}$ is a De Morgan topos).

As an example, consider the case $\mathcal{E} := \operatorname{Sh}(\mathbb{R})$.  Then $2_{\mathcal{E}}$ can be described as the sheaf where $2_{\mathcal{E}}(U)$ is the locally constant functions $U \to 2$.  Thus, in the case $U := \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, $2_{\mathcal{E}}(U)$ has a section which is 0 on $(-\infty, 0)$ and 1 on $(0, \infty)$.  We also see that the given section of $2_{\mathcal{E}}(U)$ does not extend to a global section of $2_{\mathcal{E}}(\mathbb{R})$.  On the other hand, $h_U$ is $\lnot\lnot$-dense in $h_{\mathbb{R}} \simeq 1_{\mathcal{E}}$.  This shows that $2_{\mathcal{E}}$ is not a $\lnot\lnot$-sheaf since $\operatorname{Hom}(h_{\mathbb{R}}, 2_{\mathcal{E}}) \to \operatorname{Hom}(h_U, 2_{\mathcal{E}})$ is not surjective.

Comment: It might be worth noting that one could guess that the inclusion wouldn't preserve $2$ since it is the *right* adjoint in a geometric morphism, thus unlikely to preserve coproducts.

Comment: So all this tells us that $+_{\mathcal{E}}$ and $+_{\mathcal{E}_{\neg\neg}}$ are calculated differently. That is, even if $1_{\mathcal{E}}$ is a $\neg\neg$-sheaf, $2_{\mathcal{E}_{\neg\neg}}=1_{\mathcal{E}}+_{\mathcal{E}_{\neg\neg}}1_{\mathcal{E}}$ is different from $1_{\mathcal{E}}+_{\mathcal{E}}1_{\mathcal{E}}=2_{\mathcal{E}}$.